# MySQL Query still executing after a day..?

Tags: macos, mysql, hung

I'm trying to isolate duplicates in a 500MB database and have tried two ways to do it. One creating a new table and grouping:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table as
SELECT * FROM items WHERE 1 GROUP BY title;
```

But it's been running for an hour and in MySQL Admin it says the status is Locked.

The other way I tried was to delete duplicates with this:

```
 DELETE bad_rows.*
        from items as bad_rows
        inner join (
                select post_title, MIN(id) as min_id
                from items
                group by title
                having count(*) > 1
        ) as good_rows on good_rows.post_title = bad_rows.post_title;
```

..and this has been running for 24hours now, Admin telling me it's Sending data...

Do you think either or these queries are actually still running? How can I find out if it's hung? (with Apple OS X 10.5.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
alter ignore table items add unique index(title);
```

This will add a unique index and at the same time remove any duplicates, which will prevent any future duplicates from occurring. Make sure you do a backup before running this command.

Comment: Nice solution! Have to change any TEXT or BLOB fields to VARCHAR before indexing though. Thanks!